# How to add a line in files recursively bash?

Tags: bash

I use the command to add one line at the beginning of the php files in the current directory and its subdirrectories recursively.

```
    find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i -e "/<?php/a\\
Sometext" *.php \;
```

But it adds `Sometext` many times (instead of one) only in php files in the current directory (instead of all). What I did wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't pass the files found by `find` to the `sed` command, but the files found by the shell glob `*.php`. Before `find` is executed, the `*.php` is expanded and your command becomes

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed ... 1stMatch.php 2ndMatch.php ... \;
```

Afterwards, `find` will for each found file execute the command

`sed ... 1stMatch.php 2ndMatch.php ...`

You probably wanted to write

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i -e '/<?php/a\\
Sometext' {} \;
```

For each file, `find` executes `sed` and replaces `{}` by one file name.
In this case, you could even write `{} +` instead of `{} \;` such that `sed` is executed only once on all files at once, instead of once for every file – this will speed up your command drastically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped.

Comment: Sure I will. Just it asks me to wait 6 mins to be able to accept.